# Code Review Blog - Phase 1 - Raise the idea on the meta site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, blog

> **On Hold** [*SE Community Devs:*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15626183#15626183)
>
> The short of it is, it's kinda on us to make something that works, and we don't really do that. There isn't any real proper integration between the systems and the authors suffer as a result of it. Ultimately leading to fairly ill fates to most all of the blogs. We're looking to fix all this but it's going to take some time, and we feel that it'd be better that we have people wait (or perhaps even prepare) for a more complete blog experience that we'll offer down the road.

---

Having a [community blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) for Code Review could be an interesting idea. The real quesiton is, if we do want a community blog, what should we talk about in this blog?

Here are some pseudo-random ideas:

- About Code Review itself. How to write a good question or a good answer. What's on/off topic here (it won't hurt to remind what's good and what's not). Why most of the questions migrated on Code Review are actually off-topic for this website.
- About the common issues in the most popular languages on Code Review (C#, Java, C++, Javascript, C).
- About common bad advice and misconceptions that are often seen during code reviews.
- About the evolution of Code Review (introduction of MathJax, graduation...).
- About the community of Code Review (how to understand the popular community memes).

Anyway, we will need to be organized to create such a thing. The post linked above (and [linked here again](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) ) defines a process for establishing the blog (and you should read that whole blog post since it is full of valuable information):

1. **Raise the idea on the meta site (this post ...)**
2. [**Define the purpose and scope.**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/code-review-blog-phase-2-define-the-scope)
3. [**Recruit contributors.**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/code-review-blog-phase-3-recruit-contributors)
4. [**Plan a schedule.**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/code-review-blog-phase-4-plan-a-schedule)

On the 'instructions', Stage 1: *Raise the idea*, has this to say:

> *A community blog needs the involvement of community members.  These blogs don’t exist to be the personal blog of a community member.  They are both for and run by the community.  It needs to be something the community collectively wants and will cultivate.*

That said, I would like to have your opinion about the creation of such a community blog. Do you have any idea about what would the contents be? Would you be ready to contribute to the blog?

Comment: Once we start, we would have to find contributors to keep it going indefinitely. Do we get reputation points for writing articles?

Comment: I think this question should get more visibility. And I'd happily volunteer for this, I like writing stuff.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I agree, more exposure.

Comment: @200_success Do we always write stuff to get points?

Comment: No, but it helps to have an additional motivator, especially a year later when the novelty has worn off.

Comment: @200_success Indirectly we might get points, if we link to particular good answers in the blog entries.

Comment: *[steals idea](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1446/)* >:D

Answer (score 17):

## Yes

Code Review should have a blog.

The benefits I see are:

- a mechanism for less fact-based / more opinion based content that the Q&A component
- another way to allow the community to participate and express themselves... perhaps:

  - no formal 'bloggers' per se
  - 'committee' of some sort that 'vettes' submissions.
- A place to describe the culture of Code Review in a way that is less structured (places to extend/describe the reasoning for some of the rules, etc.).
- more exposure to Code Review - something else for google to hit.
- presents Code Review as a more mature, less 'beta' site.

Answer (score 16):

1. Code Review with a blog is a very good idea.
2. Although many codes are posted here for review, I think the common points can be accumulated and as a learning be shared in the blog along with some code snippets.
3. This can help in analysis, and will also invite people who would not come to CodeReview post because they were not concerned with the code under discussion, but with a blog post on guidelines, they will come due to inquisitiveness, and this will generate more analysis and good practices.
4. And the blog will be like a more mature information source.

My vote in favor.