# Code Review Blog - Phase 4 - Plan a Schedule

Tags: discussion, status-declined, blog

> **On Hold** *SE Community Devs:*
>
> The short of it is, it's kinda on us to make something that works, and we don't really do that. There isn't any real proper integration between the systems and the authors suffer as a result of it. Ultimately leading to fairly ill fates to most all of the blogs. We're looking to fix all this but it's going to take some time, and we feel that it'd be better that we have people wait (or perhaps even prepare) for a more complete blog experience that we'll offer down the road.

---

Anticipating ongoing interest, adding phase 4 question:

> *Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and  posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but you should post at least once a week.*

### So, what's the plan?

Backreference to other phases of the blog series.

1. [**Raise the idea on the meta site**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/code-review-blog-phase-1-raise-the-idea-on-the-meta-site)
2. [**Define the purpose and scope**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/code-review-blog-phase-2-define-the-scope)
3. [**Recruit contributors**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/code-review-blog-phase-3-recruit-contributors)
4. **Plan a schedule.** (this post ...).

Comment: Whatever happened to this project?

Answer (score 11):

We don't have a blog yet, so the dates ought to be relative to some hypothetical start date...

I suggest post one be posted at T, where T is the Friday immediately following our blog's launch date.

- T : 1st post
- T +2 weeks: 2nd post
- T +4 weeks: 3rd post
- T +6 weeks: 4th post

Let's kick-start with a post every 2 weeks for the first 5 posts. 1.5 months down.

- T +10 weeks: 5th post
- T +14 weeks: 6th post
- rinse & repeat monthly/ 4-week cycle

---

## Post One

Let's play. This is the launcher. Let's put the *Community* in *Community Blog* and make a meta-contest to determine who will post it. Details [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/code-review-blog-post-one-contest).

## Post 2

@Edward blogs about why the CR Community is so awesome.

## Post 3

@200_success (TBC) reviews the WordPress authentication system.

## Post 4

@Mat's Mug discusses the importance of having a peer review process.

## Post 5

@SimonAndréForsberg blogs about Test-Driven Development.

## Post 6

@Mat's Mug discusses on SOLID and Dependency Injection.

## Post 7

[TBC] round table discussion about the overall quality of content on Code Review.

Comment: Did you mean +10 weeks?

Comment: I would add that the first articles should all be ready even before the blog has been launched. That way, we'll be sure to have a perfect schedule for the first posts.