# Code Review Blog - Post One Contest

Tags: discussion, status-declined, blog, contest

> **On Hold** *SE Community Devs:*
>
> The short of it is, it's kinda on us to make something that works, and we don't really do that. There isn't any real proper integration between the systems and the authors suffer as a result of it. Ultimately leading to fairly ill fates to most all of the blogs. We're looking to fix all this but it's going to take some time, and we feel that it'd be better that we have people wait (or perhaps even prepare) for a more complete blog experience that we'll offer down the road.

---

### What's this about?

Looks like [Code Review wants a blog](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/code-review-blog-phase-1-raise-the-idea-on-the-meta-site).

There's [people that are willing to contribute](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/code-review-blog-phase-3-recruit-contributors).

And [we have a plan for the first 7 posts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/code-review-blog-phase-4-plan-a-schedule).

There's something special about the first post on a *[hypothetical]* shiny new blog. We only make a first impression once.

## Sharpen up!

Let's put the *Community* into *Community Blog* - sharpen up your pencils dear reviewers...

**It's time for a little writing contest!**

> [image: image of an old-school pencil sharpener]
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apsco_Vacuhold_pencil_sharpener_13.jpg</sub>

---

### Rules

Write a short excerpt that captures the essence of what the first blog post should be all about.

- Maximum 1024 characters (markdown included) in your answer.
- Must have a [ideally nice and catchy] `###Title`
- Only needs to be a sketch /outline /excerpt /summary: it's not the final version anyway (did you think our blog entries would be < 1024 characters?).
- **Last entry must be submitted by 2014-05-16 11:59:59 PM**

Vote for the best idea!

---

**The winning entry will  become the first community blog post in the History of Code Review, when/`if (blogs.Exists("Code Review Blog"))`**

---

*(to be continued...)*

Comment: Can we flag blogs? *This blog appears to be off-topic because it is not about linked-lists.*

Answer (score 9):

## Let's get this started

Hello, I'm Clippy. It looks like you're trying to start a *Code Review* Blog. Would you like to:

- get help with writing a “hello world” entry?
- write the blog without help?
- give me your delicious brainz?

*BLAM!* Oh, sorry if zombie Clippy was annoying you – we aren't that fond of zombies ourselves. In fact, we had quite the infestation going on until recently, when [insert jokes about the mission here]

Well, it's not quite that easy. But during “the mission”, a wider group of CR regulars found together, united by [clean code and stuff. List stuff we do]. But some topics which we'd like to talk about don't quite fit into the Q&A-concept of Stack Exchange. And that's where this blog comes in.

We currently have a number of posts in the pipeline covering [various topics that are peripheral to Code Review]. Come again in two weeks to see the next instalment of “The Code Review Blog” :-)

Until then: why not contribute something to the site? [ask, answer, or vote]

---

and here's the whole thing:

## Let's get this started

Hello, I'm Clippy. It looks like you're trying to start a *Code Review* Blog. Would you like to:

- get help with writing a “hello world” entry?
- write the blog without help?
- give me your delicious brainz?

*BLAM!* Oh, sorry if zombie Clippy was annoying you – we aren't that fond of [zombies](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511) ourselves. In fact, we had quite the infestation going on until recently, when we deployed on [a mission to rid <del>the earth</del> *our site* of unanswered questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/999). But what do you do with battle-hardened veterans used to banging out answer after answer? Cue Marie Antoinette: Let them write blogs.

Well, we're not quite that bored. But during “the mission”, a wider group of CR regulars found together, united by a fascination of software craftsmanship, clean code, and [linked lists](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1705). We review code, hang out in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8595), discuss our [beta-progress](/questions/tagged/beta-progress) on [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com), and hold regular [code challenges](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekend-challenge?sort=newest) to encourage us to add quality content to the site. But some topics which we'd like to talk about don't quite fit into the Q&A-concept of Stack Exchange. And that's where this blog comes in.

We currently have a number of posts in the pipeline covering various topics that are peripheral to Code Review: our progress as a community, code reviews of open-source software, and meditations on quality software development. Come again in two weeks to see the next instalment of “The Code Review Blog” :-)

Until then: why not contribute something to the site?

- You've written some code which you know could be better? Check by the [help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make sure your question fits the scope of our site, and [ask a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to get some feedback!
- You're after your daily fix of nit picking? Look no further – we have [code in a wide selection of programming languages](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) for you to (constructively!) criticise.
- Don't want to type anything? No problem – just embark on a five minute mission to seek out [new questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) and [excellent answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is:answer), to boldly upvote [where too few have upvoted before](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/169776/one-vote-short). And by reading an answer before voting on it, you'll even learn something new in the process! Seriously though, upvoting is really really important, as it shows appreciation to those who have taken their time to scrutinise the given code and write a response detailing how to apply best practices in that real-world situation.

Thank you for listening, I'll hope to see you around!

Comment: See the source for full draft. The outline has exactly 1024 bytes as markdown, but thanks to UTF-8 a few less characters.

Comment: Well done. [You win a TShirt.](http://i.imgur.com/1IwREPv.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

## puts("Hello World!");

Oh hey, that's a perfect line in your C implementation of Hello World! But wait, where's the rest of it? We gotta see that too!

Here on Code Review we chew on your working but crappy beast of a code and spit out stunning elegant beauties. Ok that's a lie, but we do tell you how to do it. And that's actually better:

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

### So what’s this blog about?

This blog is about bringing to you relevant info,
on our mission to "elegant and optimized-to-the-bone implementations for all programmers".
It's also a scheme to trick you into becoming a regular contributor ;-)
[replace with the *actual* reasons]

We'll talk about stuff like:

- Why our community is so awesome
- Why doing code reviews is so damn important and how to get/trick/coerce all your cowerkers into the habit
- How to do unit tests right and make TDD an effortless habit

Stay tuned, we're only getting started!

Comment: Btw, I don't like long posts. This is not a sketch. I would make something short and sweet like this as the first post.

Comment: I like this idea - but then I think if we go with this, the 2nd post should be up sooner.

Comment: @Mat'sMug yup, I agree!