# People looking for help?

Tags: discussion

A brief glance at this SE seems to tell me it's more filled with "why doesn't this code work" questions as opposed to "How could this code work better" (which I believe is the actual point of this SE).

Best way to enforce the intention of this SE?

Comment: Could you give some examples of (open) questions?  Questions about "why doesn't this code work?" are clearly off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, but the premise that Code Review has more off-topic than on-topic question is completely ridiculous. **As I am writing this, only 4 of the 50 most recent questions are on hold.**

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question. The [rulebook](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is pretty clear about non-working code:

> 1. Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> 2. Did I write that code?
> 3. Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> 4. Do I want the code to be good code, (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> 5. **To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?**
> 6. Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

I agree that the rules could make it more visible that non-working code is off-topic. But there's people that *don't* read the manual and then there's people that *won't* read the manual.

---

We recently ran a contest here on meta, where [the community voted on ad suggestions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1781/23788) (at this time it's still showing up on the Community Bulletin). This is our winning entry:

[image: def review(code): | """ Share the code | you are working on | for peer review. | """ | for line in code: | if line.smells: | improve(line) || {CR} tough questions, | smart answers.]

The ad is now in effect on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/community-promotion-ads-2014/6627#6627) and [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014/252457#252457). I find it makes a great job at capturing the site's essence, but there's indeed no explicit emphasis on *working* code. And [the ad is quite successful, too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/251196).

---

We eventually want to have [our own blog](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1712/23788), which will give us an additional tribune for promoting *Code Review* and what CR is all about.

That's currently on hold until further notice though.

---

If anyone has any more ideas, **bring them!**

Comment: I could actually say that saying "that you are working on" also implicitly implies not working code. However I doubt that the ad itself changed the mentality.

Answer (score 3):

As you are talking about **enforcing the intention** of this SE-Site.

That's what we as Users do everyday, we comment, vote up, down, close and reopen questions, we edit, we chat, we ask, we answer,

## **we are** [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

And by doing so, everyday, we **enforce the intention of what we see as Code Review**